# Is it awkward to say "get out of harm's way" when you ask your child to get out of the hot kitchen?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Your child is around the hot kitchen where you are cooking.

Is it awkward to say "**get out of harm's way**"?

"**out of harm's way**" is an idiom. I know that it is often used in battles or in more severe and dangerous situation.

Can we say it when the child is in a hot kitchen as the hot kitchen is quite a dangerous place?

Comment: Sure, it's reasonable. Is there a reason you're concerned about this phrase in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, it depends on the context.

You **would not** typically use that idiom as an exclamation or order to another person because it's too general. For example, you **would not** yell at Ned:

> Ned, get out of harm's way! (not typical)

because it's not clear what the "harm" is. And if Ned doesn't know what the harm is, he might not know what to do to get out of its way.

An exclamation would typically be more specific, such as:

> Ned, get away from the hot stove!

If you don't use it as an exclamation, I don't think you're limited at all. For example, if you were speaking to the child, you might say something like:

> Children should remain outside the kitchen to keep them out of harm's way.